# codeigniter - display data from data base in dropdown

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am creating an application in codeigniter for the form we want country and state in drop down on change selection of country
Controller is like

```
public function user()
{
        $data   = array();
        $this->load->model('enquiry');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $data['result'] = $this->enquiry->get_reqtutor();
        $data['countries'] = $this -> country_model -> get_countries();
        $this->load->view('Table\DemoHistory',$data);
}

function get_states($country) {
     $this->load->helper('url');
     $this->load->model('state_model');
     header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
     echo(json_encode($this->state_model->get_states($country)));
}
```

**and model is like
state_model**`

```
<?php
class State_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
         $this -> load -> database();
    }
    function get_states($country = null){
         $this->db->select('state_id, state_name');
         if($country != NULL){
             $this->db->where('country_id', $country);
         }
         $query = $this->db->get('state_master');
         $states = array();
         if($query->result()){
             foreach ($query->result() as $state) {
                 $cities[$state->state_id] = $state->state_name;
             }
             return $states;
         } else {
             return FALSE;
         }
    }

}
?>
```

country_model

```
<?php
class Country_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
         $this -> load -> database();
    }

    function get_countries() {
         $this -> db -> select('country_id, country_name');
         $query = $this -> db -> get('country_master');

        $countries = array();

        if ($query -> result()) {
             foreach ($query->result() as $country) {
                 $countries[$country -> country_id] = $country -> country_name;
             }
             return $countries;
        } else {
             return FALSE;
        }
     }

}
?>
```

Ajax is like

```
 <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#country').change(function(){ //any select change on the dropdown with id country trigger this code
             $("#cities > option").remove(); //first of all clear select items
             var country_id = $('#country').val(); // here we are taking country id of the selected one.
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: /mtb/Schedule/get_states/"+country_id, //here we are calling our user controller and get_cities method with the country_id

                 success: function(cities) //we're calling the response json array 'cities'
                 {
                     $.each(cities,function(state_id,state_name) //here we're doing a foeach loop round each city with id as the key and city as the value
                     {
                         var opt = $('<option />'); // here we're creating a new select option with for each city
                         opt.val(state_id);
                         opt.text(state_name);
                         $('#cities').append(opt); //here we will append these new select options to a dropdown with the id 'cities'
                     });
                 }

             });

         });
     });
 // ]]>
</script>
```

and view is

```
<?php $countries['#'] = 'Please Select'; ?>

<label for="country">Country: </label><?php echo form_dropdown('country_id', $countries, '#', 'id="country"'); ?>
 <?php $cities['#'] = 'Please Select'; ?>
<label for="city">State: </label><?php echo form_dropdown('state_id', $cities, '#', 'id="cities"'); ?>
```

i am getting country name while my state value is not comming in dropdown please help........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Things to consider about your code:**

You have an error here url: `/mtb/Schedule/get_states/"+country_id`, missing double quote at the beggining. Always use a debugging tool, like [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), it will show you the javascript errors.

Another thing, the code

```
if($country != NULL){
```

should be

```
if(!is_null($country)){
```

take a look at [is_null function](http://uk.php.net/is_null).

Another thing, instead of `application/x-json` json header you should use `application/json`.

Another thing, the code

```
echo(json_encode($this->state_model->get_states($country)));
```

should be

```
echo(json_encode($this->state_model->get_states($country)));
exit;
```

otherwise unexpected result might be appended to the final json. `Example:` CodeIgniter profiling.

Another thing, the code

```
$countries = array();

if ($query -> result()) {
     foreach ($query->result() as $country) {
         $countries[$country -> country_id] = $country -> country_name;
     }
     return $countries;
} else {
     return FALSE;
}
```

should be

```
$countries = array();

foreach ($query->result() as $country) {
    $countries[$country -> country_id] = $country -> country_name;
}
return $countries;
```

because having no countries and returning `FALSE` will give you an error in `form_dropdown` function, take a look inside it. The same goes for `get_states` function.

This is how much I see in a preliminary look of your code.